# ¿Cómo identificar el número mayor en una estructura repetitiva (While)? en Java

Tags: java

¡Hola!
Estoy realizando un ejercicio lo cuál requiere de hacer una estructura repetitiva que debe almacenar los datos de estatura y identificar cuál es el más alto. (El número mayor)

Mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int opc=1;
    int estatura, suma;
    
    suma=0;
    
    //
   
while(opc == 1){
    System.out.println("Ingrese la altura");
    estatura = sc.nextInt();
    
    
    System.out.println("¿Desea registrar otra estatura?"+
                                        "\nSi = 1 o No= 2");
        opc = sc.nextInt();
}

    System.out.println("La estatura más alta es: "+suma);
 
}
```

Lo que tengo preparado hasta ahora, un While que se repita hasta que yo se lo indique, una fotografía del caso de la consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me podrían ayudar a realizar dicha estructura? Se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: La primera vez que preguntas puedes hacerlo fuera del ciclo, luego solo sobre escribes si el numero es mayor al almacenado

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int opc=1;
int estatura, estaturaMayor;

estaturaMayor=0;

//

while(opc == 1){
  System.out.println("Ingrese la altura");
  estatura = sc.nextInt();
  //Verificamos si la nueva estatura es mayor que la estatura mayor anterior
  if(estatura > estaturaMayor){
     //Si la estatura es mayor, se la asignamos a la variable mayor
     estaturaMayor  = estatura;
  }

  System.out.println("¿Desea registrar otra estatura?"+
                                    "\nSi = 1 o No= 2");
  opc = sc.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("La estatura más alta es: "+estaturaMayor);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

agrega una condicional if luego de capturar la altura

```
estatura = sc.nextInt();
    if(suma<estatura){
    suma=estatura;
    }
```

si  `suma` es menor a estatura este tomara su valor de esa manera te aseguras que suma se quede con el valor mas alto

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int opc=1;
    int estatura, suma;
    int mayor=0; 

    suma=0;
    
    //
   
while(opc == 1){
    System.out.println("Ingrese la altura");
    estatura = sc.nextInt();
    
    if(estatura>mayor) { mayor = estatura } 
    
    System.out.println("¿Desea registrar otra estatura?"+
                                        "\nSi = 1 o No= 2");
        opc = sc.nextInt();


}

    System.out.println("La estatura más alta es: "+mayor);
 
}
```

Donde:

- Declaras la variable global `mayor` y la inicializas en `0`.
- Cada que ingresas una estatura, comparas con una condicional `if` si la estatura nueva es mayor a la estatura previamente registrada como "la mayor".
- Finalmente, en el resultado imprimes `mayor`, esta variable vendrá cargada con la estura más grande.